# JS: Access nested array by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have this function:

```
const dateFormatUsEnglish = new new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US");
const debug = dateFormatUsEnglish.formatToParts(base);


// return value: 
[ 
  { type: 'weekday',   value: 'Monday' }, 
  { type: 'literal',   value: ', '     }, 
  { type: 'month',     value: '12'     }, 
  { type: 'literal',   value: '/'      }, 
  { type: 'day',       value: '17'     }, 
  { type: 'literal',   value: '/'      }, 
  { type: 'year',      value: '2012'   }, 
  { type: 'literal',   value: ', '     }, 
  { type: 'hour',      value: '3'      }, 
  { type: 'literal',   value: ':'      }, 
  { type: 'minute',    value: '00'     }, 
  { type: 'literal',   value: ':'      }, 
  { type: 'second',    value: '42'     }, 
  { type: 'fractionalSecond', value: '000' },
  { type: 'literal',   value: ' '      }, 
  { type: 'dayPeriod', value: 'AM'     } 
]
```

Now I wanna write if statements like "if debug[2].month.value === x..." in order to replace / correct the user's input live. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform result Array to Mapped Object with

```js
const mapped = result.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { 
    accumulator[currentValue.type] = currentValue.value 
    return accumulator
}, {})
```

Now you can access with `mapped.month` and have 12 value

Comment: In my case debug[x].value where x points to the arr cell I could get my value, but your answer is nice!